# Understanding $\lor~E$ in Natural Deduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm reading Frank Pfenning's [Lecture Notes on Natural Deduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/317-f18/lectures/02-natded.pdf). It's reasonable that the following $\lor$-elimination rule is incorrect since we can have any theorem $\alpha$ given a single theorem $\beta$.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \lor \beta\\
\hline\hline
\alpha
\end{array}
$$

The real $\lor$-elimination rule is given by:

$$ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \lor \beta \quad [\alpha] \cdots \psi \quad [\beta] \cdots \psi \\
\hline\hline
\psi
\end{array}
$$

where by $[\alpha]$, $[\beta]$ is denoted an assumption of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. However what prevents someone from doing something like this?

$$ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \lor \beta \quad [\alpha] \cdots \alpha \quad [\beta] \cdots \alpha \\
\hline\hline
\alpha
\end{array}
$$

Which looks like the previous mistake (i.e. I want to derive any $\alpha$ from a $\beta$), but this is a valid inference. How does this differ from the wrong one?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I guess the question is about the third rule in the OP. He believes that it is not valid, but actually it is valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - Exactly! This is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: The or elimination rule is just proof by cases.  It might be more clear to you if you write it as $$\dfrac{\text{Case}_1 \lor \text{Case}_2 \quad \text{Case}_1 \to X \quad \text{Case}_2 \to X}{X}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elimination rule for $\lor$

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\alpha \lor \beta \qquad [\alpha]\cdots\psi \qquad [\beta]\cdots\psi}{\psi}\lor_e
\end{align}

is valid for any formula $\psi$, in particular for $\psi = \alpha$.

The case $\psi = \alpha$ for $\lor_e$ is not equivalent to the rule

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\alpha \lor \beta}{\alpha} (*)
\end{align}

which is unsound because in $(*)$ an important hypothesis (present in the rule $\lor_e$ with $\psi = \alpha$) is missing: that $\alpha$ is derivable from the further assumption $\beta$.
In other words, the rule $\lor_e$ in the case $\psi = \alpha$ can be rewritten as (since $\alpha$ is trivially derivable from the further assumption $\alpha$)
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\alpha \lor \beta \qquad [\beta]\cdots\alpha}{\alpha}
\end{align}

which is indeed perfectly derivable in natural deduction.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm finally able to get it.

Comment: @Aristu - Glad to hear that.